# Access Violation Error when reading a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

**According to the book: `How to C Programming - Eighth Edition (by Deitel brothers)` this code reads the word "Hello":**

```
#define SIZE 20

int main()
{
   char MyStr[SIZE];

   printf("Enter your word: ");
   scanf("%19s", MyStr);
}
```

**This picture is from the [Sixth Edition online](https://faculty.psau.edu.sa/filedownload/doc-11-pdf-1f6b1a8f2f8e794b944062f2d5f8e875-original.pdf):**

[image]

**But when I do:**

```
int main()
{
   char MyStr[20];

   printf("Enter your word: ");
   scanf_s("%19s", MyStr);
}
```

**I get Access Violation error:**

[image]

**What is that I am doing wrong?**

Comment: I recommend that you [read the documentation for `scanf_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2017). It's a special function that requires special extra arguments in some cases.

Comment: "`scanf_s` _requires the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or [. The buffer size is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable._"

Comment: You've fallen into the trap of Microsoft telling you to use `scanf_s` and lies about `scanf` not being "safe" and whatnot - there is no change in safety here between `scanf` and `scanf_s` *given* the format from the book.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's not the documentation for `scanf_s`. It is found in Annex K of the standard, the "bounds checking interface".

Comment: @Lundin Unfortunately Visual Studio have their own variants of the "safe" functions, that are similar but not the same as the standard functions of the same name (at least they used to be a little different).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah and the whole reason for including Annex K was to please MS, who don't give a damn... And so Annex K will unlikely be implemented by any compiler and removed from the standard (as proposed in a good DR to the committee).

Comment: Anyway, seems like yet another C book of questionable quality...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between scanf and scanf_s.  The latter requires the length to be specified.  So your code should be changed to:

```
int main()
{
   char MyStr[20];

   printf("Enter your word: ");
   scanf_s("%19s", MyStr, sizeof(MyStr));
}
```

or

```
int main()
{
    char MyStr[20];

    printf("Enter your word: ");
    scanf("%19s", MyStr);
}
```

Comment: My IDE is not allowing me to use scaf(), so I added the size parameter to scanf_s() and it worked.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah and make the solution even more complex by finding a better book

Comment: @SandraK Learning bad, non-standard practices with an outdated compiler isn't going to make you a decent C programmer. Visual Studio is at best to be regarded as a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Add  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS to linker options and it should allow you to use scanf and other "unsecure" methods if you don't want to use safe ones. Visual Studio by default prefers if you use secure ones